# delete records based on another table using join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In bigquery, I want to delete record using below query. It is not working. I think join is faster to delete. how do I write this query in bigquery?

```
DELETE a
FROM  `Data_a` a
INNER JOIN `Data_b`  b
  ON a.PolicyNumber=b.PolicyNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this approach wherein we use the `JOIN` statement as a subquery of the `DELETE` statement and the subquery is our primary condition for the deletion.

```
DELETE FROM `Data_a`
WHERE  PolicyNumber IN (SELECT a.PolicyNumber
FROM   `Data_a` a
INNER JOIN `Data_b`  b
ON a.PolicyNumber=b.PolicyNumber)
```

Comment: @slashie If you find my answer helpful, you may upvote/accept it for the benefit of the community in the future that may encounter the same use case.